# Googlemaps JQuery strange behaviour function call on click

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm new into Jquery and currently facing a strange behaviour that I don't understand. Any reference is welcome.

I'm adding a marker on Googlemaps and when I click on the Marker I'll save the X and Y mousecoordinates so I can animate a box to that location. Everything works well but when I check the console and own datalogbox I see that each time I click on the Marker the function saveXandY is executed +1 times.

Code below:

```
// addmarker on click if markermode is on
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){  
    if (markerMode == true) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    } 
});

function addMarker(location) {
    var image = {
        url: defaultMarkerIcon,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(defaultMarkerSizeX,defaultMarkerSizeY)
    };  

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        draggable: defaultMarkerDraggable,
        icon: image,
        map: map,   
    });

    markerMode = false; 
    marker.customInfo = i;
    logData("Marker custominfo: " + marker.customInfo); 
    markers.push(marker);       
    i++;    

    map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: ''}); 
    addListener();
}

function addListener() {        
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {      
        logData("Marker custominfo: " + marker.customInfo); 
        saveXandY();    
    });
}

function saveXandY() {
    $('#map').click(function(e) {
        coordsX = e.pageX;
        coordsY = e.pageY;
        logData("Set X + Y: " + e.pageX + "," + e.pageY);
        console.log("SaveXandY")
    }); 
};

// simple log to databox
function logData(console){
    $("#data").prepend(console);
    $("#data").prepend('<br />');
}
```

Console looks like this:

```
Set X + Y: 708,164
Set X + Y: 708,164
Set X + Y: 708,164
Set X + Y: 708,164
Set X + Y: 708,164
Marker custominfo: 0
Set X + Y: 708,164
Set X + Y: 708,164
Set X + Y: 708,164
Set X + Y: 708,164
Marker custominfo: 0
Set X + Y: 712,164
Set X + Y: 712,164
Set X + Y: 712,164
Marker custominfo: 0
Set X + Y: 712,164
Set X + Y: 712,164
Marker custominfo: 0
Set X + Y: 712,164
```

Also after adding a marker it seems that the code inside the function saveXandY() is also executed when clicking on the map. This should not be the case.

If anyone got a suggestion I'll be happy :)
Ömer

Comment: Each time you call `saveXandY()`, you are binding a new click event to `#map` without unbinding any previous ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$('#map').click(function(e) {
        coordsX = e.pageX;
        coordsY = e.pageY;
        logData("Set X + Y: " + e.pageX + "," + e.pageY);
        console.log("SaveXandY")
    });
```

with this:

```
$('#map').off().on("click", function(e) {
        coordsX = e.pageX;
        coordsY = e.pageY;
        logData("Set X + Y: " + e.pageX + "," + e.pageY);
        console.log("SaveXandY")
    });
```

"Off" will remove the current listener and add the new one. A better solution would be to call saveXandY() only once if you can.

More on "off": http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Thanks Nicholas I was a bit confused but now it's clear that every time the function saveXandY is called I'm adding another listener :)